# Android - is there a way to fill a CalendarView before displaying it?

Tags: android, calendarview

I'm trying to find a way to use CalendarView in my app, but it should have some data preloaded before being displayed (some days will have time slots busy, according to user's info stored in a DB). What is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set view visible after the operations.

```
calendarObect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//(do stuff)
calendarObect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @MaRin, but that's not quite what I'm looking for... It's more like I need a CalendarView with slots showing a "busy" message. Say, for example, May 15th will have a busy slot from 10 to 10:30 am... All these busy slots will be prefilled before showing the CalendarView, and the data will be gathered from a database according to the user selected.